# Extract rows from a table with regular expression hive sql

Tags: regex, string, hive, row, rlike

[image: Check the table info here]

Please check the link for the result and table info. I need to query rows 
with value '343' in Col B with a regular expression . All columns are strings . Also please be kind enough to point any good learning materials in how to write good REGEX in Hive . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
select * from tablename where regexp_like(B,'(.*)(343)(.*)');
```

hive equivalent is :

```
select * from tablename where rlike(B,'(.*)(343)(.*)');
```

Answer (score 1):

For Hive use this:

```
select * from tablename where B rlike '343';
```

Checking it works:

```
hive> select '123435' rlike '343';
OK
_c0
true
```

Negative test:

```
hive> select '12345' rlike '343';
OK
_c0
false
Time taken: 1.675 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Hive uses Java flavor regex. You can find good reference and practice here: https://regexr.com/ and of course [regex101](https://regex101.com/)